# Merging sas data sets without a key variable

Tags: merge, sas

I am attempting to merge two data sets without a single key variable. The data looks like this in both data sets:

```
study_id.....round....other variables different between the two sets
A000019....R012....etc  
A000019....R013  
A000047....R013  
A000047....R014  
A000047....R015  
A000267....R014
```

This is my code...

```
DATA RAKAI.complete;
length study_id $ 8;
MERGE hivgps2 rccsdata;
BY study_id round;
RUN;
```

I've tried to merge by study_id and round which are the only two variables shared across the data sets. But it just stacks the two sets creating double the correct number of IDs. The combination of "study_id" and "round" provides a unique identifier, but no one variable does. Does is just make the most sense to code a new unique id by combining the two variables that are shared by both data sets?

Many Thanks

I realized I can post the code that I meant to deal with potential unwanted spaces here.

```
DATA hivgps2;
SET hivgps2;
study_id = compress(study_id);
round= compress(round);
RUN;

DATA rccsdata;
SET rccsdata;
study_id = compress(study_id);
round=compress(round);
RUN;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is the correct format for merging by multiple variables. Records from both datasets are included, so if none of the keys match then the result will be the same as if you used SET instead of MERGE.

Are you sure that there is any overlap between the two sets of data? Check that your variables are the same length.  If they are character then make sure the values are consistent in their use of upper and lower case letters. Make sure that the values do not have leading spaces or other non-printing characters.  Also make sure you haven't attached a format to one of the datasets so that the values you see printed are not what is actually in the data.

In your clean up data steps you should force the length of the variables to be consistent.  Also you can compress more than just spaces from the values. I like to eliminate anything that is not a normal 7-bit ASCII code.  That will get rid of tabs, non-breaking spaces, nulls and other strange things. In normal 7-Bit ASCII the printable characters are between ! ('21'x or 33 decimal) and ~ ('7E'x or 126 decimal).

```
data hivgps2_clean ;
  length study_id $10 round $5 ;
  set hivgps2;
  format study_id round ;
  study_id=upcase(compress(study_id,compress(study_id,collate(33,126))));
  round=upcase(compress(round,compress(study_id,collate(33,126))));
run;

proc sort; by study_id round; run;

data rccsdata_clean;
  length study_id $10 round $5 ;
  set rccsdata;
  format study_id round ;
  study_id=upcase(compress(study_id,compress(study_id,collate(33,126))));
  round=upcase(compress(round,compress(study_id,collate(33,126))));
run;

proc sort; by study_id round; run;

data want;
  merge hivgps2_clean(in=in1) rccsdata_clean(in=in2);
  by study_id round;
run;
```

Comment: Looking through the data there should be nearly complete overlap. I have no formats, the values look the same and I had this code in there to try to deal with potential spaces, sorry for the formatting mess I imagine that is will be.                                                                             DATA hivgps2;
SET hivgps2;
study_id = compress(study_id);
round= compress(round);
RUN;

DATA rccsdata;
SET rccsdata;
study_id = compress(study_id);
round=compress(round);
RUN;

Comment: Sweet jesus Tom it worked! I need to study that cleaning code so I can do it next time, many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try that, or you can just use a proc sql join:

```
proc sql;
    create table rakai.complete as select
        a.*, b.*
        from hivgps2 as a
        full join rccsdata as b
        on a.study_id = b.study_id and a.round = b.round;
quit;
```

Comment: I may be applying it wrong, but when I slot in the code it still gives me an uncombined set of 82206 observations (each set contains 41103). I'm shooting for one fully merged set of 41103 obs. Am I reading you wrong?

Comment: If you have `study_id` and `round` variables that identify observations in both datasets, this should join them accordingly. Can you post samples of your datasets?

Comment: Certainly, but I'm not sure how to do it the right way. My first question and all

Comment: Could you point me toward a resource for how to do it the right way? manythanks